'CallbackQueryHandler' problem in python telegram bot
I have the following code snippet.

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    print("start function called")  # دیباگ
    user_id = str(update.message.from_user.id)
    data = load_data()

    if user_id in data:
        await show_main_menu(update, context)
        return ConversationHandler.END
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text('لطفاً نام خود را وارد کنید:')
        return GET_NAME


In this piece of code, it is first checked whether the user has already registered or not. If the user is not registered, the GET_NAME function will be executed, but if the user is registered, the ConversationHandler function will end.
I have different commands in ConversationHandler that I need to execute one command instead of returning ConversationHandler.END based on the conditions selected by the user.
Please guide me how to fix this section.
The source code for my ConversationHandler is as follows.
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            GET_NAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_name)],
            GET_GENDER: [CallbackQueryHandler(get_gender, pattern='^(male|female)$')],
            SET_NEW_NAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, set_new_name)],
            CONFIRM_GENDER: [CallbackQueryHandler(confirm_gender, pattern='^(male|female)$')],
            SEND_TO_ADMIN: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, send_to_admin)],
            OBSERVER_PANEL: [CallbackQueryHandler(handle_observer_panel)],
            DISCIPLINE: [CallbackQueryHandler(handle_discipline, pattern='^discipline_')],
            KICK: [CallbackQueryHandler(handle_kick, pattern='^kick_'),
                   CallbackQueryHandler(handle_kick_type, pattern='^(shot|nato)_')],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        per_chat=True  # تغییر این خط به per_chat
    )

I want to use app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build() method.
My expectation is to provide a logical solution to solve this question. This function ends instead of providing one of the choices based on the user's needs, I need the function to be executed correctly. My goal and expectation is a learning process.

I don’t quite understand what you want and what doesn’t work? Just return the state you need and the function will run

i want selected object run, e.g. when user send "ارتباط با ادمین" the "SENT_TO_ADMIN" run.

It doesn't work that way.  When you run a state machine, you first return the state, and after that the user writes something.  If you want to handle messages from a user, use a message handler.

To modify your start function and ConversationHandler setup to allow for executing different commands based on conditions, you can use a dictionary to map conditions to states or functions. This will enable you to dynamically choose the next state based on user conditions instead of always returning ConversationHandler.END.
Here are steps:

Modify the start function to handle different user conditions.
Update the ConversationHandler to include all possible states and
transitions.

    
    async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
        print("start function called")  # دیباگ
        user_id = str(update.message.from_user.id)
        data = load_data()
    
        if user_id in data:
            # Example condition to choose next state based on user data
            user_condition = data[user_id].get('condition', 'default')
            next_state = condition_to_state(user_condition)
            await update.message.reply_text('Redirecting based on your condition...')
            return next_state
        else:
            await update.message.reply_text('لطفاً نام خود را وارد کنید:')
            return GET_NAME
    
    def condition_to_state(condition):
        condition_map = {
            'gender': GET_GENDER,
            'new_name': SET_NEW_NAME,
            'confirm_gender': CONFIRM_GENDER,
            'send_to_admin': SEND_TO_ADMIN,
            'observer_panel': OBSERVER_PANEL,
            'discipline': DISCIPLINE,
            'kick': KICK
        }
        return condition_map.get(condition, ConversationHandler.END)
    
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            GET_NAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, get_name)],
            GET_GENDER: [CallbackQueryHandler(get_gender, pattern='^(male|female)$')],
            SET_NEW_NAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, set_new_name)],
            CONFIRM_GENDER: [CallbackQueryHandler(confirm_gender, pattern='^(male|female)$')],
            SEND_TO_ADMIN: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, send_to_admin)],
            OBSERVER_PANEL: [CallbackQueryHandler(handle_observer_panel)],
            DISCIPLINE: [CallbackQueryHandler(handle_discipline, pattern='^discipline_')],
            KICK: [CallbackQueryHandler(handle_kick, pattern='^kick_'),
                   CallbackQueryHandler(handle_kick_type, pattern='^(shot|nato)_')],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        per_chat=True
    )
    
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()
    
    app.add_handler(conv_handler)
    
    app.run_polling()


the code you've write its not my answer. i want to have auto chosse option as the user send message, e.g. the user send "ارتباط با ادمین" the "SENT_TO_ADMIN" run, the user send "تغییر نام" the "SET_NEW_NAME" run
